# How to display an error dialog and quit in the middle of a loading dialog

Tags: android, dialog, android-asynctask

My android application begins by loading all the necessary data, while displaying a loading dialog:

```
// Load data in background, while updating the loading dialog.
(new AsyncTask<Void, String, Void>() {
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        publishProgress(getString(R.string.loading_a));
        if!(loadA())
            showErrorDialogAndQuit();
        publishProgress(getString(R.string.loading_b));
        if(!loadB())
            showErrorDialogAndQuit();
        publishProgress(getString(R.string.loading_c));
        if(!loadC())
            showErrorDialogAndQuit();
        return null;
    }

    protected void onProgressUpdate(String... progress) {
        dialog.setMessage(progress[0]);
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        // Update the UI.
        updateUI();
        dialog.dismiss();
    }
}).execute();
```

The methods `loadA()`, `loadB()`, and `loadC()` potentially can fail, returning false. At this point, I would like an error message to be displayed, and the application to exit in the method `showErrorDialogAndQuit()`.

I've tried creating it as follows, but it always seems to throw an error after the application has quit, something to do with the loading dialog not having a window anymore.

```
public void showErrorDialogAndQuit() {
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            AlertDialog aDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MyActivity.this).setMessage("Fatal error.").setTitle("Error")
                    .setNeutralButton("Close", new AlertDialog.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(final DialogInterface dialog, final int which) {
                            // Exit the application.
                            finish();
                        }
                    }).create();
            aDialog.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onKey(DialogInterface dialog, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
                    // Disables the back button.
                    return true;
                }

            });
            aDialog.show();
        }
    });
}
```

What is the best way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out all I needed to do was make the progress dialog close naturally before `finish()` got called:

```
if(!loadA()) {
    showErrorDialogAndQuit();
    return null;
}
```

This works by creating the error dialog, which runs in another thread, and then returning null to the `AsyncTask` causing it to run `onPostExecute()` and dismiss the progress dialog. Then when the close button in the error dialog was pressed and `finish()` called, everything could close properly.

The only drawback to this approach is that if something more substantial than updating the UI was happening in `onPostExecute()`. In that case, you could modify the argument type and test it to see what to do.

Answer (score 0):

If you can execute loadB only after successful loadA I would recommend to change the logic of your code. You may use a final state machine approach with 3 states where stateB get triggered after stateA has finished.

Also updating the UI can be done nicely using a handler. The logic might look like this:

1. in main body start Thread loadingA
2. in threadA 
   if successful send msg A_success to main body
   else send msg A_failed to main body
   threadA ends here
3. main body receives msg through the handler and continues
   if received A_success -> start Thread loadingB
   else end (or whatever you want)

Starting  threadA looks like this:

```
  new Thread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        loadingA();
    }
    }).start();
```

Within loadingA you send the msg back to the main body like this:

```
 public void loadingA() {
    ...do your loading...

    then to inform the main body...

    Message msg = mHandlerToReceiveTheResultFromLoadingThread
            .obtainMessage(MESSAGE_UPDATE_RESULT_OF_LOADING_A);
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putBoolean(RESULT_OK_INFO, true or false);
        msg.setData(bundle);
        mHandlerToReceiveTheResultFromLoadingThread
            .sendMessage(msg);

        }
```

in the main body the `mHandlerToReceiveTheResultFromLoadingThread` looks like:

```
public final Handler mHandlerToReceiveTheResultFromLoadingThread = new Handler() {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {

        if (DEBUG)
        Log.i(this.getClass().getSimpleName(),
            "-> "
                + Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[2]
                    .getMethodName() );
        switch (msg.what) {
        case MESSAGE_UPDATE_RESULT_OF_LOADING_A: {
        boolean result_ok = msg.getData().getBoolean(RESULT_OK_INFO);

        if (result_ok)
            ...continue with loadingB;
            else
               show your message that it failed and exit;
        }
        break;

        }

    }
```

Hope this helps...

EDIT: calling finish at end of logic in an activity:

```
        this.myBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {   
                String msg = "Hello, I have finished and started another activity";
                doOtherActivit(msg); 
                finish();
            }
        });
    }

public void doOtherActivity(String msg) {
        Intent i;
        i = new Intent(this, OtherActivity.class);
        i.putExtra("Task", msg);        
        startActivity(i);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, how exactly does this help with my error dialog/closing application problem?

Comment: all you have to do is to show your message in case any of the loadA,B,C fails -> see the code for mHandlerToReceiveTheResultFromLoadingThread in the if(result_OK) else branch. Hope I could explain well this time...

Comment: And I won't have any weird errors or crashes if I do it that way? The question was mainly about how to close the app without crashing due to GUI components than how to structure the program flow.

Comment: yes this will work because you handle the failure case in the loadA thread which does not have anything to do with the UI directly. It reports back to the UI thread through the handler. Are you afraid that loadA might crash? You should make sure that loadA never crashes, even if it fails loading. Either you catch the exception in failure mode or you use a timeout when exceeded to know your load routine failed. Nevertheless, this will work in all cases, since the UI thread is save and just waits for incoming result messages from your loading routines.

Comment: what do you mean with "weird errors or crashes". There is really nothing weird about the fact that when a UI component disappears due to some problems that the app crashes when trying to send a msg to this disappeared UI element. The point simply is to handle the error cases explicitly and reporting them back savey to the UI thread.

Comment: I meant that calling `finish()` from the error dialog caused some other UI components to get angry and crash the app. So you're saying if I show my dialong, and call `finish()` from where you said to in your code, the loading dialog won't throw any exceptions?

Comment: I don't know exactly where you have called finish() and where the code wanted to continue, but if you call finish at the end of your code logic where NOTHING ELSE will assume that the activity you finished still exists, then there is no problem at all. I always call finish when switching to another activity in cases where I am sure I will not continue or come back. I added a sample to my answer...

Comment: I'm still not sure how your solution helps my problem. I've added additional code to my question to make it clearer, my apologies for doing so earlier.

Comment: you are finishing the dialog which goes away anyway bec you clicked on OK. You should instead invoke a method of your UI main thread to finish this one and not the dialog

Comment: But where would I put it then? I want the application to end once the user has clicked the button in the dialog.

Comment: write a method in your UI code called iAmDone(){finish();} and call this from the dialog

Comment: Got it, I needed to let the progress dialog close naturally before I called `finish()`, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/10200863/343486. Thanks for your help!